# Localization in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, localization

I need to localize my application, and I need also that the translator will have easy access to the files he needs to translate. I see that interface files (the `.xib`s and the strings inside them) are divided into languages.

The solution would be manually rewriting all the `.xib`s? And what if some strings are programmatically shown in the application? Maybe I need something like a global parameter that tells the application which language is set. Anyway, I think that Mac applications automatically show the right `.xib` depending on the system language.

Is there a "best" thing to do when programming with translatable interfaces?

Answer (score 5):

What I think you need is Localization.

Where you use strings in your code:

- Create a new Localizable.strings file (File -> New File -> iOS -> Resources -> Strings file)
- Select this file and Show the file inspector (Command + Option + 1)
- Click the add button under localization and add a default language (I expect English) and the other languages you want.
- You'll notice that you have a little arrow next to your Localizable.strings file, if you click it, you can see the languages that you've added.
- For each phrase you want to translate, use the following syntax:

  `"key" = "value";

  "hello" = "bonjour";`
- In your code where you want to use the translation, use `NSLocalizedString(@"hello", @"hello");` (The second parameter is a comment, it doesn't matter what value you use here)

When it comes to nibs, you'll need to manually change the strings and re-arrange the text fields etc in each nib.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't know if it matters, or I did something wrong, but all these steps are correct except that I couldn't get it to work naming the strings file "Localization.strings".  But when I used "Localizable.strings" instead, it worked perfectly.