# Language Translations in IOS App without using online APIs

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working on application having 10-12 languages, there language has to translated from one to another. App is offline so can't use diffrent API's and also the range of words is too large and undefinite to create localized files, is there any other solution or library for language translations in IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you're fundamentally asking: "Is there an inbuilt multilingual translation dictionary available for use?" The answer to that is "no".

A `library for language translation` is just a multilingual dictionary. This would effectively be the same as localising your files and as you've indicated, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Then how should i go for that if i have to do the language translation

Comment: This was actually my very first answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7220293/916299